# Sub Query - Part Numbers and Quantity

Tags: ms-access-2010

Looking to find all part numbers (d046d) with at least one record having vaule greater than zero.

```
d046d                        e024a
ABC123                       0
ABC123                       0
ABC123                       0
123ABC                       0
123ABC                       1
123ABC                       0
1A2B3C                       0
1A2B3C                       0
```

All I want returned is 123ABC

```
SELECT d008g, d046d, e024a
FROM 20121
WHERE (20121.[d046d])=(select sc.d046d from 20121 as sc where e024a >0)
```

This will error becuase it will find multiple d046d in the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is just those parts with a quantity greater than zero, then your where clause should probably just say

```
WHERE e024a > 0
```

Now you say you want part numbers where at least one record is > 0, so then I can conclude that you only want to see each qualifying part number once - this is best achieved by using
DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d008g, d046d, e024a
FROM 20121
WHERE e024a > 0
```

Comment: Should have pointed out that this is the subquery part of a query.  Afraid it only works by itself.  When I add it to the main I get the error that it can return more than one value.  Working on that now.

Comment: No luck, everything the I write to works by itself will not work within the main query.

Comment: What is the main query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an In Operator.  [In Operator Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208859(v=office.12).aspx)

```
SELECT d008g, d046d, e024a
FROM 20121
WHERE (20121.[d046d]) In (select sc.d046d from 20121 as sc where e024a >0)
```